# Latest Sidekick update causes VBoxManage failed exit code 126

Tags: nativescript

Just installed the latest update Version 1.14.0-v.2018.11.15.3(latest). Install updated Nativescript CLI to 5.01, but on starting Sidekick I now get an error as per the title of this post followed by VirtualBox.app No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this issue to our attention.

The reason why you get this error when opening an app in Sidekick is because Sidekick tries to get the emulator images available on your machine at this point and fails. This is related to a feature we introduced recently - you can now start an emulator from Sidekick UI.

Having said that, we'll resolve the issue by moving the code that gets the emulator images to execute when you actually open the emulator images dialog - that way, you will not get a confusing error initially, but will still get the errors, if any, if you want to use the new feature and there is a problem.

Comment: OK Thanks, As a temporary fix I had to install VirtualBox.